# How do I solve this limit

Tags: limits, graphing-functions

[image]

**Find the limit ${x \to 6}$ if $ f(f(x))$ **

Any idea how to solve this graphical question on limits?

Comment: Not exists, as $x \to 6$, $f(x) \to 2$ and limit of $f$ at 2 does not exist.

Comment: @user3313320 Except as Emilio points out,  in a neighborhood of 6,  $f(x)>2$,   so the second limit turns into a right hand side limit,  which does exist

Comment: @Alan oops! Sorry I didn't see that.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

In a neighborhood of 6 $f(x)$ is continuous and we have $f(x)>2$ , so :

$$
\lim_{x \rightarrow 6}f(f(x))= \lim _{f(x) \rightarrow 2^+} f(f(x))=\lim _{y \rightarrow 2^+} f(y)
$$
and you can see this limit from the graph.

Comment: second limit $f(f(x))$ or f(x) ?

Comment: Second limit is of $f(f(x))$ than substitute $f(x)=y$.

Comment: so answer is 5?

Comment: Yes, it is correct!